# How to stop service worker returning outdated index.html?

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I have a problem with the Angular service worker returning an old version of index.html (from the date the service worker was installed) that is driving me bonkers!

Basically on a fresh startup of the browser (chrome) the old index.html is being served by the service worker resulting in a defunct mainxxx.js being loaded and due to the IIS rewrite rule I have in play to support deep linking mainxxx.js returns back with the contents of index.html (side effect of service worker returning wrong index.html in first place)

When I soft or hard refresh the browser tab, the correct index.html is loaded and all is fine... that is, until I close the browser and start again at which point the old index.html is served up again :O

As you can see from the screenshot below (sorry about the redaction), I have turned off caching via the cache-control header..

[image]

To complicate things... when I look at the Application tab in the dev tools, I can see multiple instances of the cache for various versions (I guess) of the worker, one has the old index.html and a different one has the newer version cached!

While I understand the general idea around service workers, I'm getting lost in all the code that is provided by the angular service worker so would really love if one kind person would point me in the direction of a solution that would help me :)

Thanks!

=====
As requested my ngsw-config.json is the standard out-of-box version..

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Can you add your ngws-config.json in the question ?

Comment: Are you running on a CDN ? you need to make sure that you have no-cache set to your index.html and your ngsw.json and manifest files

Comment: Is the DevTools open when you try this ?

Comment: Yup... but it also fails with the dev tools closed :)

Comment: Ok because multiple instances is probably due to DevTools https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#developer-tools. So if you test in incognito browser without DevTools, this problem is still alive ?

Comment: erm.. I can try the incognito route, but surely the problem will be hidden as part of that `private` route is that nothing is cached right?

Comment: I think private browser just has an other temporary scope. So cache mechanism will works but everything will be dropped on browser close.

Comment: Well.. it worked in private mode but as mentioned the cache is dropped on close, so that only proves that CloudFlare is returning upto date stuff (but I know that already)

thanks anyway @Gilsdav

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185158/discussion-between-andycwk-and-gilsdav).

Comment: in developer tools click on Application and then on clear storage

Comment: haha.. yeh, thanks @MukulSharma  now let's find a solution that works for the other 99.99% of the users that aren't developers ;)

at the moment... I'm seriously thinking of just turning off service workers on this project :O

Comment: @andycwk did you find a solution for this? I can't believe this bug hasn't been fixed already.

Comment: @andycwk I have the same problem - how did you resolve this?

Comment: are you subscribed to service worker updates? 
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications